# Slow reading hundreds of files

Tags: c#, performance, file, binary

I have problem with processing of more binary files. I have many many folders, in each there is about 200 bin files.

I choose 2 of these directories, then all bin files (their paths) from these 2 directories save to List, and make some filtering with this list. At the end of this, in list is about 200 bin files.

Then I'm iterating over all filtered files, and from each read first 4x8 Bytes (I tried `FileStream` or `BinaryReader`). All this operations take about 2-6 seconds, but only for the first time. Next time it's fast enough. If nothing happens with files for a long time (about 30 minutes), the problem appears again.

So probably it's something about caching or what?

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: file system caching. get more RAM

Comment: Buy a solid-state drive?

Comment: Can you show us a bit of code?

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that the handles to the files are disposed and that's why after a while the GC removes them and it takes longer or simply that the files are loaded in RAM by the OS and then it serves them to you from there and that's why it is faster, but that is not the issue, the process runs slow because it is slow, it isn't relevant that it is faster the 2nd time because you mustn't rely on that.

What i suggest is to parallellise as much as possible the processing of those files to be able to harness the full power of the hardware at hand.

Start by isolating the code that handles a file and then run the code within a `Parallel.ForEach` and see if that helps.

Comment: Parallellising won't help if the bottleneck is the storage medium (e.g. the hard drive), which is quite likely (I mean, it would still help a little as he could be doing IO and processing in parallel, and is a good suggestion, but might not actually solve his problem)

Comment: You are right, but it is the only place where he has the power to optimize the whole process and decrease the total time. How effective it will be remains to be seen.

Comment: @RB while in general I agree simple computation gives us 200 * 4 Kilobytes of data (only 32 bytes is read from file, but we know disks can only read on sector basis, which is 4 Kilo max nowdays) that gives us roughly 800 kilobytes of data per 2-6 seconds. This is VERY small amount of data even for a VERY slow disk. Directory fragmentation might be an issue - that's true, but I wouldn't completely negate possibility of code optimization.

Comment: @DavidGoshadze I read it as "All the operations *in total* take 2-6 ms". If we assume the files are randomly distributed (which the author suggests they are), and assume a typical 10ms seek time per file (could be even slower for a laptop) then that's 2 seconds, just in seeking.

Comment: Yes that I called directory fragmentation. Defragmenting dir could help a little.

Comment: @DavidGoshadze But he's not accessing contiguous files, and he's not accessing entire files, he's seeking within the files, so he'll still be spending lots of time seeking rather than reading for the hard drive.

Comment: Not the point. Optimizing file locations within directory one can significantly decrease seek time and gain performance. Btw he is seeking not within files, he reads first 4x8 Bytes. Seek occures when reading "next" file

Comment: Thank's you for your findings...I haven't tried parallellising yet (running on NET 3.5 and Threading.Tasks is included in NET 4 unfortunetly). But I found, that if I only open every file, and don't read 4x8B from this, resulting time goes down to circa 500ms...

Comment: Maybe FileStream and BinaryReader are cacheing all file. Some function from win API, which can really read only few bytes from start of file, could be solution...

Comment: Wow, I tried it on SSD, and it takes now down to 40ms...Problem is that it must run on older PC with SATA :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your drive is going to sleep (typically a drive will be configured to power down after 15-30 minutes). This can add a significant delay (5 seconds would be a typical figure) as the hard-drive is span back up to speed.

Luckily, this is an easy thing to test. Just set the power-down time to, say, 6 hours, and then test if the behaviour has changed.

Comment: I have HDD Turning OFF set to "never", so it isn't the solution unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it was likely - it just happened to fit the symptoms described perfectly!