# Is my binary files caching method stupid?

Tags: c#, file, binary

In my C# application i have to read a huge amount of binary files, but at the first run, reading those files using FileStream and BinaryReader, takes a lot of times. But the second times you run the app, reading the files is 4 times faster.

After reading this post "[Slow reading hundreds of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961361/slow-reading-hundreds-of-files)" I decided to precache the binary files.

After reading this other post "[How can I check if a program is running for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773748/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-is-running-for-the-first-time)", my app now can detect if it is the first time it is running then I precache the files by using this simple technique "[Caching a binary file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925356/caching-a-binary-file-in-c-sharp)".

Is there another way of precaching huge amount of binary files?

**Edit:**

This is how I read and parse the files

```
f_strm = new FileStream(@location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
 readBinary = new BinaryReader(f_strm);

 Parse(readBinary);
```

The Parse() function just contains a switch statement that I use to parse  the data.
I don't do anything more complicated. As an example, I tried to read and parse 10.000 binary files of 601KB, it took 39 secondes and about 589.000 cycles to read and parse the files.

When I run again the app, it finally took about 45.000 cycles and 1.5 seconds to read and parse.

**Edit**:
By "huge" amount of files I mean millions of files. It's not always the case, but most of the time I have to deal with at least 10.000 files.  The size of those files can be between 600Ko and 700MB.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ok thanks for editing it. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I'd suggest caching only when needed, since caching a lot of information that you might not use wouldn't be efficient IMO

Comment: This is very vague so it is hard to tell what is slowing the read the first time, it could be a lot (disk asleep, caching).  Can you post an example or a profile result that shows why it is slow?

Comment: @pollirrata Yep that's right, but all of the data inside the binary files are used so in my case, it's worth it to precache while the app is launched for the first time.

Comment: It's very important that you put a number to the term "huge".  For some people this means many MB, for some many GB, for others many TB or more.  What do you mean, "huge"?

Comment: You have not determined the reason why it is so much faster the second time. In particular, the change in the number of CPU cycles seems unlikely to be due to caching. You need to find out what the problem is before fixing it.

Comment: How can I investigate further? what are the tools I should use? which point should I exactly investigate further? what should I monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read them once and discard the results. That puts them into the OS cache and makes future reads very fast. Using the OS cache is automatic and very safe.

Or, make yourself a `Dictionary<string, byte[]>` where you store the file contents keyed by the file path. Be careful not to exhaust available memory or your app will fail or become very slow due to paging.

Comment: Could you elaborate the first part. How to do that OS cache? any link regarding this could be helpful?

Comment: The OS caches data that you read. The next read will be just a memcpy from the OS cache to the application buffer. This is common for all OS'es.

Comment: @usr I did this
new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(__PATH_TO_FILE_)); and it works perfectly as while I run the app for the second time, it is pretty fast.

Comment: If it's working fine, what's the question then? My recommendation is to just use the OS cache if possible, and othrwise cache as a byte[]. No need for a MemoryStream.

Comment: The question is "Am I doing the right thing?". I just don't want it working fine, I also want to be sure that I'm not doing it stupidly.
A "yes" or "no" could answer the question but I also wanted some explanation of what is exactly happening after precaching, because the difference of cycles between the reading of non-precached binary  files and precached ones is about 544.000 cycles which is huge to me.

Comment: Yeah apart from the things I've said this is a workable approach. You're good.